# Hide old, closed questions from main page

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, closed-questions

I noticed that questions about rejected patents, questions that were closed or put on hold by a moderator, etc. are still accessible from the main page. This creates clutter and makes it harder to find relevant content.

Shouldn't these posts be "archived" or hidden from the main page so that people don't have to waste time looking at them? They could still be searchable, though.

Comment: I think the broader problem here is that we have a lot of closed / on hold questions. The signal is lost in the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Closed questions remain on the site for a short period of time to give the author (and users) time to respond to followup. But there are a lot of support links leading from various places on the Internet *into* this site, so oftentimes users simply do not know what the site is about or what we do here.

That's why most closed questions are simply *deleted* within about a week or two of being asked. User posting erroneous content rarely return, so if the question was closed as off topic or somehow inappropriate for this site, that content is typically removed as part of the routine maintenance of this site.

Comment: To clarify, I asked this question because I saw closed questions being linked to from the main page and found that these links were distracting me from being able to find open questions.